# Using Apollo Graphql Fragments as generic types in Swift

Tags: swift, graphql, apollo

I am fairly new to the Swift programming language. I am trying to create a util function that takes a generic.

```
class Utils {
  static func formatArtists<T: ArtistDetails>(_ artists: [T]) -> String {
    return artists.map({ artist in
        return artist.name
    }).joined(separator: ", ")
  }
}
```

I get two errors for this piece of code

```
 Type 'T' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'ArtistDetails'
 Value of type 'T' has no member 'name'
```

I think I need to extend a `protocol` or something.

I want to be able to call the helper function like this.

```
Text(Utils.formatArtists(track.artists))
Text(Utils.formatArtists(mix.artists))
```

With both `track` and `mix` artists using the `ArtistDetails` fragment.

Artist Details gets generated by Apollo swift library

```
public struct ArtistDetails: GraphQLFragment {
  /// The raw GraphQL definition of this fragment.
  public static let fragmentDefinition: String =
    """
    fragment ArtistDetails on Artist {
      __typename
      id
      name
    }
    """

  public static let possibleTypes: [String] = ["Artist"]

  public static var selections: [GraphQLSelection] {
    return [
      GraphQLField("__typename", type: .nonNull(.scalar(String.self))),
      GraphQLField("id", type: .nonNull(.scalar(GraphQLID.self))),
      GraphQLField("name", type: .nonNull(.scalar(String.self))),
    ]
  }

  public private(set) var resultMap: ResultMap

  public init(unsafeResultMap: ResultMap) {
    self.resultMap = unsafeResultMap
  }

  public init(id: GraphQLID, name: String) {
    self.init(unsafeResultMap: ["__typename": "Artist", "id": id, "name": name])
  }

  public var __typename: String {
    get {
      return resultMap["__typename"]! as! String
    }
    set {
      resultMap.updateValue(newValue, forKey: "__typename")
    }
  }

  public var id: GraphQLID {
    get {
      return resultMap["id"]! as! GraphQLID
    }
    set {
      resultMap.updateValue(newValue, forKey: "id")
    }
  }

  public var name: String {
    get {
      return resultMap["name"]! as! String
    }
    set {
      resultMap.updateValue(newValue, forKey: "name")
    }
  }
}
```

```
protocol GraphQLFragment : GraphQLSelectionSet
```

Thanks

Comment: could you show the code for `ArtistDetails`?

Comment: Updated with ArtistDetails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift you might prefer to write it like

```
extension Collection where Element == ArtistDetails {
    var formatted: String {
        map(\.name).joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}

Text(track.artists.formatted)
```

You can't write a generic like `<T: ArtistDetails>` because ArtistDetails is a struct so doesn't support subclassing, and isn't a protocol, so T can't be any type that implements the protocol or "is a" ArtistDetails.  There's no need for a Utils class - if you ever need a namespace like that an enum (with no cases) would be preferred as a type that can't be instantiated.

Comment: Thanks, this will work for sure. Although get this type issue ```Type '(S) -> S.FormatOutput' cannot conform to 'StringProtocol'```

Comment: We don't see your code, but that error is saying you have something that is a _function_ (from S to S.FormatOuput), and a function isn't a string, but if you call() it, then you will have a string